# How to decode XML page during parse?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, encoding

I have an XML that actually has url-encoded quote marks and other symbols (" appears as %22, ' as %27 and so on). 
I'm trying to parse this page without these symbols, but they still appear as %22 and %27.

This is my code:

```
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        url = new URL(feed);

        xr.setContentHandler(rh);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        xr.parse(is);
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: That the parsed text also shows %22 instead of ".

Comment: That's exactly as it should be, nothing wrong here.

Comment: But I want it to format to ". I can't have the user seeing all these %22's everywhere.